# Array Display and Alert Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am using the Chicago Employee Data to push the results of Chicago Employee's Salary Information as well as departments. I've been able to get the name and salary to work, but can't seem to get the Department part to work.

Additionally, I am trying to make an alert if there are no matching names after searching for them, but my alert doesn't work either. I don't want anyone to do the code for me, just tell me what I'm doing wrong!

```js
ChicagoEmployeesQuery = function(searchKey) {
  var url,
    url =
    "https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/xzkq-xp2w/rows.json" +
    "?search=key_word&jsonp=?";
  this.query = url.replace("key_word", searchKey);
}

ChicagoEmployeesQuery.prototype.getList = function(callBack) {
  $.getJSON(this.query, function(response) {
    var i, results;
    results = [];
    for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i += 1) {
      row = {
        name: response.data[i][8],
        title: response.data[i][9],
        department: response.data[i][10],
        salary: response.data[i][14]
      }
      results.push(row);
    }
    callBack(results);
  })
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Salary Info Demo</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ChicagoEmployees.js"></script>
  <script src="demoLS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Salary Info</h1>

  <p>Enter first or last name: <input type="text" id="key-word" size="20" /></p>

  <p><input type="button" id="start" value="Submit Query" /></p>

  <h2>First Matching Employing and Salary</h2>
  <div id="result">
    First result appears here
  </div>

  <h2>List of All Matching Names</h2>
  <div id="names">
    All Matching Names Appear Here
  </div>

  <h2>List of All Matching Names + Departments</h2>
  <div id="namesDepartment">
    All Matching Names + Departments Appear Here
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
postResult = function(list) {
  //var nameList, i, glist;
  glist = list;
  if (list.length > 0) {
    $("#result").html(list[0].name + "<br />" + list[0].salary);
  }


  postResult = function(list) {
    //var namesDepartmentList, i, glist;
    glist = list;
    if (list.length > 0) {
      $("#namesDepartment").html(list[0].name + "<br />" + list[0].department);
    }
  }

  nameList = "";
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    nameList = nameList + list[i].name + "<br />";
  }
  $("#names").html(nameList);



  namesDepartmentList = "";
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    namesDepartmentList = nameList + list[i].name + "<br />";
  }
  $("#namesDepartment").html(namesDepartmentList);
}

submit = function() {
  var searchWord = document.getElementById("key-word").value;
  query = new ChicagoEmployeesQuery(searchWord);
  $("#result").html("waiting...");
  query.getList(postResult);
  if (key_word.isEmpty()) {
    alert("No Matching Records Found");

  }
}


submit = function() {
  var searchWord = document.getElementById("key-word").value;
  query = new ChicagoEmployeesQuery(searchWord);
  $("#namesDepartment").html("waiting...");
  query.getList(postResult);

}

$(function() {
  $("#start").click(submit);
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information so we don't have to pour over every line in your code. What does *"doesn't work"* mean? Are you getting any errors in your developer's console? Are you getting any results? Where in your code are you having problems?

Comment: @ScottMarcus When I run my code, I am able to receive an output of just the names under "List of All Matching Names and Department", when I would like to receive the names + department. And the alert should appear if there are no matching results after hitting the button

Comment: Yes, but please answer the questions I asked in my last comment about errors and the location in your code of the issue. Have you logged `response` from your AJAX call to see if the data is even coming back to you? If it is, then the solution is easy, if it's not, then you have an entirely different issue that we can't help with.

Comment: @ScottMarcus specifically when "namesDepartmentList" is supposed to run in my last section of javascript code, it should give an output of the name + department. Right now it's only giving me the names

Comment: Sorry to sound like a broken record, but please check your developer's console for any errors and let us know. Also, did you log `response` like I suggested? You keep telling me what you want, but you're not telling me what I'm asking you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus no console errors, which is why I am confused as to why it's not working! And I apologize for not understanding your question fully, I just ran the code and logged a response with no errors.

Comment: Did the response include the data you want and, if so, please edit your question and show us what the `response` structure looks like.

Comment: Also, I'm not talking generically about "a" response. I'm talking about the `response` argument that is passed to your AJAX callback function in the success handler.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking for then, When I click the button to find the results, say I search "Smith", I'll get a response in the console saying "Name+Department should be displayed", but within the HTML page, only the name appears. I put the console.log statement under   'query.getList(postResult);'

Comment: @ScottMarcus The extent of my coding knowledge lies in Javascript and HTML, not AJAX unfortunately. That's what I meant when I say I don't know what you're asking for

Comment: You have the following line: `$.getJSON(this.query, function(response) {...` and following that is the code that extracts the data you want. `response` is the actual data that was returned from your API call. Add, `console.log(response)` just inside that function and run your code with the developer's console open. This is where all the data you get back will be. We need to know if the data you want is even being returned.